# IdentityServer4 login via email

Tags: email, authentication, identityserver4

What would be the best way to create a login via email?

Currently we generate a JWT and send it via email. With this procedure the JWT token will expire at some point. We would like to extend the login (e.g. with code, refresh-token, access-token).

How can you create a fully-fledged login, which you normally get by logging in with username + password?

What other ways are there to provide a login via email?

Comment: What have you tried already? I have a similar solution based on the [AspNetIdentity quickstart](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/samples/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity). You could try to implement login via email by storing a strong and unique limited time password in a database and then pass it from your client to IdentityServer with the [acr](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#acrSemantics) values. Modify your AccountController to validate the limited time password with a custom AuthenticationHandler and log the user in.

Comment: The variant sounds interesting. Is it comparable to the password reset via mail?
We will have a look in that direction.
What exactly triggers "acr" on the IdentityServer?

Would the suggested variant allow an auto login or would the user still have to enter his username and (limited) password?